# When will I need to define HAVE_IFADDRS_H?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I am figuring out the mechanism in the roscpp package, and I found there's codes in the function determineHost() in network.cpp:

#ifdef HAVE_IFADDRS_H

...

#endif

There's a comment : fall back on interface search, which will yield an IP address

But I don't know what does it mean~

Can someone give me a brief explanation?

Thanks in advance, Ricky.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12493/when-will-i-need-to-define-have_ifaddrs_h?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2012-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The HAVE_IFADDRS_H symbol is defined by the ros build system if your system has the ifaddrs.h header; you should never have to define it yourself.

It looks like that particular chunk of code is trying to find an outward-facing IP address to use to identify the computer it's running on.

If you want more information about it, I suggest reading the man page for getifaddrs.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1